# how to show message without html tags which is take from JoditEditor

Tags: reactjs

I take text from user by using `JoditEditor`.

```
 const editor = useRef(null);
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

 const config = useMemo(
    () => ({
      readonly: false,
      buttons: ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
    }),
    []
  );

 <JoditEditor
        ref={editor}
        value={content}
        tabIndex={2} // tabIndex of textarea
        onChange={(newContent) => {
          setContent(newContent);
        }}
        config={config}
      />
```

And I want to display that data to user without html tag and same format. But how can I do that?

Also I am trying to show message or data to user without html tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-use the html created from Jodit to display it, you will have to use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) keeping in mind the  relevant warnings.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />
```

---

If you want to extract the plain text from the returned html, you can use one if the helpers they provide, namely the [`stripTags`](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/docs/functions/helpers_html.stripTags-1.html)

So somthing like `const plaintext = Jodit.modules.Helpers.stripTags(content);`

But you will have to import the `Jodit` as well, when you import the editor.

So `import JoditEditor, { Jodit } from 'jodit-react';`